# Are Remote EJBs the right way to go?

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa

I am planning to remodel my current application and I am not sure if this is the right approach.

**Currently**
I have a *Java Enterprise* server application with *3 web-applications* and an *ejb-application* which handles the database (JPA with EJB-Facades). Everything in one single project (deployed as an `ear` file).
The web-applications are quite independent, though they all use the same database and the same entities. So, they all depend on the *ejb-application*.

**What I would like to do**
I would like to separate the web-applications, so they can run independently and I don't need to redeploy everything, only because I make a change in one application.

The idea is to create a single `jar` library that contains *remote interfaces* for the existing *facade beans*. That way I can setup the `jar` to be a server wide available library and deploy my *ejb-application* that then will implement the *remote interfaces*. 
The 3 web-applications would only have to import my library and have full access to the database.

Now, I am not even sure if this is a recommendable way, since I guess the `remote ejbs` might have a serious **impact on performance** due to serialization (or don't they **?**).

And **what about the database entity classes?** Since every web-application uses them when accessing the database, they need to be in the `jar` as well. But having an *ejb-application* for database access that does not contain the actual `entity` classes - that just feels off.

```
 ————    ————    ————                
|web1|  |web2|  |web3|              
 ————    ————    ————                
       \   |   /                    
        ———————                         ———             ———
       |  JAR  |                       |EJB|——————————>|DB |
        ———————                         ———             ———
        entity classes <---import----- db-facades
        remote ejbs  <---implement---/
```